# Extract method with parameters (C#, VS 2017)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, methods, parameters, extract

I have below code into button click:

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
 SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
 saveFileDialog.Filter = "CSV File|*.csv";
 saveFileDialog.Title = "Save CSV File";
 saveFileDialog.FileName = newCSVName;
 saveFileDialog.InitialDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments));
 saveFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;

 if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog().GetValueOrDefault(false)){
    if (saveFileDialog.FileName != ""){
       ParseStream(path, OutputResults.OUTPUT_TYPE_FILE, null, null, saveFileDialog.FileName);
    }}}
```

I'm trying to extract it to new method, because into second button I have already the same code, only one, below line is diffrent (has diffrent parameters):

```
ParseStream(path, OutputResults.OUTPUT_TYPE_SQLINSERT, tableName.Text, null, saveFileDialog.FileName);
```

After extract to new method I have already did:

```
private void SaveFileD(string nFilter, string nTitle, string newCSVName){
 SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
 saveFileDialog.Filter = nFilter;
 saveFileDialog.Title = nTitle;
 saveFileDialog.FileName = newCSVName;
 saveFileDialog.InitialDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments));
 saveFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;


 if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog().GetValueOrDefault(false)){
    if (saveFileDialog.FileName != ""){
       //.....
    }}
```

And new button click code:

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
 string nFilter = "CSV File|*.csv";
 string nTitle = "Save CSV File";
 string newCSVName = newCSVName;

 SaveFileD(nFilter, nTitle, newCSVName);}
```

But I don't know what to do with **ParseStream** method, as I'm passing diffrent parameters into two cases.

Comment: You would make the parameters that differ as parameters to `SaveFileD` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  public void MyAwesomeMethodThatDoesStuff(string path, OutputResults outputResults, string someParamater = null)
  {
     SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
     saveFileDialog.Filter = "CSV File|*.csv";
     saveFileDialog.Title = "Save CSV File";
     saveFileDialog.FileName = newCSVName;
     saveFileDialog.InitialDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments));
 saveFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;

     if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog().GetValueOrDefault(false))
     {
        if (saveFileDialog.FileName != "")
        {
           ParseStream(path, outputResults, someParamater, null, saveFileDialog.FileName);
        }
     }
  }
```

**Usage**

```
MyAwesomeMethodThatDoesStuff(@"D:\MyAwesomePath", OutputResults.OUTPUT_TYPE_FILE, tableName.Text)
```

Or

```
MyAwesomeMethodThatDoesStuff(@"D:\MyAwesomePath", OutputResults.OUTPUT_TYPE_FILE)
```

Comment: this new method? what about SaveDialog?

Comment: thanks! I used it, pass new parameter (OutputResultsParameter) and works

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unclear what you're asking, but looks like you want to change the arguments you pass to the `ParseStream` method according to the current context in the `SaveFileD` method.

Comment: I don't want to change, ParseStream is ok, but I want to know how to use it into my new method SaveFileD

Comment: @4est I've updated my answer. But again, it's not so clear what your question is.